# Create a new ViewController object only if it doesnt exist

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I use the following code to bring up a view

```
-(IBAction) openSomeView{
SomeView *sv = [[SomeView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sv animated:NO];
[sv release];
```

}

How can I detect if this view has been created already and if so, then just show it now create a new object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first declare in **@interface**

```
SomeView *sv;
```

and the you can check it

```
-(IBAction) openSomeView{
if(sv==nil)
sv = [[SomeView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sv animated:NO];
[sv release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create more than one instance using this code, since you present modally the view controller.

Else, you'd probably keep a member variable in your class and check it against nil.

EDIT: or you can implement the 'Singleton' design pattern, if that's the meaning you search.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of heavy-weight view controllers in my app. Right now I'm handling this situation as follows:

- save MyViewController to appDelegate
- in "openSomeView" method I'm checking if MyViewController was already created, if no - create it:

  ```
  -(IBAction) openSomeView {
      MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


      if ( !appDelegate.myViewController ) {
          appDelegate.myViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" 
                                                                              bundle:nil];
      }


      [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.myViewController animated:NO];
  }
  ```

Comment: How do you save your ViewController to the appDelegate? :-s